# jBehave NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, jbehave

I have a parent story which calls some common stories as below;

```
Meta: @action_text %start_action_text

GivenStories: common/s_1.story,
              common/s_2.story#{0},
              common/s_3.story,
```

I am passing parameters to 3rd story s_3.story using Meta: @action_text %start_action_text and am getting an exception.

In story 3, I have step as

```
When I select example action <action_text> on Panel (FAILED)
```

This step is failing and I am getting NullPointerException

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator.parameterPosition(StepCreator.java:377)
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator.parameterForPosition(StepCreator.java:283)
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator.parameterValuesForStep(StepCreator.java:269)
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator.access$1000(StepCreator.java:35)
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator$ParameterisedStep.parametriseStep(StepCreator.java:587)
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator$ParameterisedStep.perform(StepCreator.java:547)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner$FineSoFar.run(StoryRunner.java:499)
```

What am I doing wrong?